# An error occurred while installing .NET (7.0): .NET Acquisition Failed:

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, installation

Here is the error that keeps popping up with my experience during this problem (Ubuntu/os) :

> An error occurred while installing .NET (7.0): .NET Acquisition Failed: Installation failed: Error: Command failed: "/home/speed/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime-1.6.0/dist/install scripts/dotnet-install.sh" -InstallDir "/home/speed/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/7.0.8" -Version 7.0.8 -Runtime dotnet

1. I have tried just about everything that I could personally think of solve this problem and sad to say I still haven't had any luck.
2. Ways I've tried to solve this problem: .Uninstalling the Dotnet-Sdk framework and redownloading it multiple times. .Manually installing the dependencies/binary .Hours of Google . Added and removed from home $PATH multiple times
3. Looks like the main problem is when I try to make "Create .Net Project", the terminal will start up loading dots will start to show but it seems like it eventually times out.